# Distribution of the sum of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X_{1}$,$X_{2}$,...,$X_{N}$ be a Dirac distributed (not independent) random variables. What is the distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^{N}{X_{i}}$?

Comment: Do you mean Dirac as in "Dirac measure/distribution" = assigning all the mass to a single point? Those $X_i$ would automatically be independent (because constant). Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I mean $X_{i} ~ N(\mu,\sigma)$, where $\sigma$ goes to $0$.

Comment: If $\sigma$ goes to $0$ then $X_i=\mu$ with probability $1$ and the sum of $N$ of them is $N\mu$ with probability $1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I don't quite understand your question, and therefore simply assume that by "$\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$ with $\sigma \to 0$" you simply mean the Dirac measure $\delta_\mu$*.

The Dirac measure assigns the whole unit mass to a single point.
Therefore, to say that $X_1,...,X_N$ are Dirac distributed is to say that these random variables are almost surely constant. In particular, if $\mathcal{L}(X_i) = \delta_{\mu_i}$ for some $\mu_i\in\mathbb{R}$, then:

$\qquad \mathcal{L}(\sum_{i=1}^N X_i) = \delta_{\sum_{i=1}^N \mu_i}$.

In particular, if all $\mu_i$ are equal to a single specific $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$, then $\mathcal{L}(\sum_{i=1}^N X_i) = \delta_{N\mu}$, that is, 
$\sum_{i=1}^N X_i = N\mu$ almost surely.
Furthermore, since $X_i$ are almost surely constant, they must be independent.